# Non-keyed styles in App.xaml do not get applied to user controls

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

In my C# / WPF / .NET 4.5 project, my **App.xaml** contains the following:

```
<Application x:Class="HsWpfApplication.App"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="h1" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
      <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Light" />
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20pt" />
      <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
    </Style>
    <!-- ... -->
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
      <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Symbol" />
      <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="11pt" />
      <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,10"/>
      <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
      <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
      <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="DarkGray"/>
    </Style>
    <!-- ... -->
  </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

I also have a user control, under the sub-namespace `HsWpfApplication.Controls`, defined in the following manner:

```
<UserControl x:Class="HsWpfApplication.Controls.Manager"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    mc:Ignorable="d" 
    d:DesignHeight="600" d:DesignWidth="300">

  <UserControl.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ManagerItemDataTemplate">
      <!-- ... -->
    </DataTemplate>
  </UserControl.Resources>

  <Grid>
    <!-- -->
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
      <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource h1}" Margin="10,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left">Manager</TextBlock>
      <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Button Command="{Binding CreateNewItemCollectionCommand}"
            ToolTip="New Item Collection"
            Margin="0,10,10,10"
            Width="40" Height="40"
            FontSize="18"
            Content="&#xE130;"/>
        <!-- ... -->
      </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
    <!-- ... -->
  </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

The keyed style `h1` is applied to the `TextBlock` just fine. The non-keyed style that I want applied to the `Button`s does not work:

[image]

How do I get non-keyed styles in my **App.xaml** file to affect my user controls?

Comment: Are you defining a button style somewhere else in your UserControl?

Comment: I just tried the same setup and it works... the problem must come from  the part of the code that you didn't include here.

Comment: Properties set directly to element in View override styled properties (style is fallback, not the other way around)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add a very obvious value to your implicit style? I would suggest FontSize='48' or something like that. Perhaps the problem is that you don't have the 'Segoe UI Symbol' present on your system?